# Do gravitational waves bounce the space upwards?

Tags: gravitational-waves

I will try my best to explain.

When I think about waves, I generally tend to first visualize a stable and flat two-dimensional surface, in position 0. When a normal sine wave travel through it, it moves the surface up and down, bouncing it to, say, +1 and -1. This is true for waves in water, sound waves and even waves in the electromagnetic field.

Is this true in regards gravitational waves? Or does it only bounces the space "down", between -1 and 0?

**EDIT**

To clarify a bit more: I want to know if gravitational waves generate a repelling force, even if it is microscopic and instant. This repelling force is what I mean by "upwards".

If there is no repelling force, then the answer to this question is "no", and the gravitational waves only work by slight increasing and decreasing the attractive force. And this is what I believe it is true.

If there is actually a frame of repelling force (in the negative mass fashion), then I believe this can be technically extrapolated (by using superposition of waves) to generate anti-gravity. (I don't believe this is the case).

Comment: What is your definition of "up" in the universe?

Comment: Sound waves are longitudinal; they oscillate forwards and backwards. Electromagnetic waves can also have "circular" polarisation like a corkscrew. Water waves tend to move particles in a roughly circular motion, which is fore-and-aft out of phase with up-and-down. I believe that gravitational waves are longitudinal like sound, though I am not sure. So maybe you need to rethink how you think about waves.

Comment: @Qmechanic I mean: the "positive" position of the wave would generate a small amount of anti-gravity/repelling force.

Comment: @GuyInchbald Yes, so if gravitational waves are like sound waves in the sense that `they oscillate forwards and backwards`, then there is a moment when they provide a repelling force.

Comment: @Qmechanic Since there is a net attractive field at the start, I'd guess the wave might rather provide alternating reduction and reinforcement in the always-attractive force. But I really don't know.

Comment: Gravitational waves contract space a little in one direction while expanding it in another. Then vice versa, in wavelike fashion. Visualizing a 2D surface tends to be misleading.

Comment: Please see my edit.